# In bash, how do you evaluate date fifteen days from today

Tags: bash

I am trying write a script that prints an json file to that involves evaluating a Saturday or Sunday date two weeks in advance, need a way to evaluate date fifteen days from today in the format MM/DD/YYYY. `date -d` gives me illegal format.

```
future_date=$(date -d "+15 days" +"%m/%d/%Y")
```

Comment: your command `date -d "+15 days" +"%m/%d/%Y"` worked in my WSL environment. what do you get if your type `uname -srv` ? Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MacOS, then the flag is `-v`:

```bash
date -v '+15d'
Sun Dec 10 08:19:56 PST 2023
```

On Linux, your own command line is correct:

```bash
date -d '+15 days'
Sun Dec 10 08:20:01 PST 2023
```